# Where does the getgroups Linux system call get data from

Tags: linux, bash, ldap

I'm debugging a problem where when I log in I get an error `cannot find name for group ID 387`.  I'm trying to figure out what this group is supposed to be and why my user is associated with it.

Using `strace` I found that `getgroups` is called when I start bash and it returns

```
getgroups(6, [20, 106, 387, 513, 2385, 2447]) = 6
```

When I looked at `/etc/group` I did not find a group 387.  But my question is why `getgroups` would have returned that number in the first place.

I'm using Ubuntu 12.04, but I log in with LDAP.  When I log in to a different machine with the same account I get a different list of numbers (`getgroups(7, [106, 513, 515, 516, 519, 520, 2503]) = 7`).

So I'm wondering what the source of the information that `getgroups` queries is.  I'm guessing that my problem is some mismatch between local and LDAP groups, but I'm not sure how all of this works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The different sources of information and their priority are defined in the `/etc/nssswitch.conf` configuration file.  This configuration files list which NSS modules should be used when functions like `getgroups()` or `getpwent()` and others are used.

Your post suggest that your system use an LDAP directory as a source for users and groups, so the groups that you are seeing likely comes from the `libnss_ldap` module. Depending on the configuration of `/etc/nsswitch.conf`, locally defined groups may override what the LDAP NSS modules returns.  The LDAP NSS modules is also maybe configured differently between your two hosts.